# How to get DebugDiag to show method names in the stack trace?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.6, debugdiag

I am trying to get to the bottom of a crash in a .NET 4.61 web application running under IIS.  I got Windows to generate memory dump on crash.  I then loaded the .dmp file into DebugDiag and added another SYMBOL folder that contained the entire application including .PDBs for all the DLLs.

However, all I got was DLL names with `Unknown` for a method name + an offset.  What am I missing or what can I do to make the method names appear?

[image]

Comment: you need PDB files for these DLLs. But the issue is in `il_stub_pinvoke`

Comment: @T.S. I do have PDB files for these DLLs.  As far as `il_stub_pinvoke`, I don't think that's the problem.  It's a stack overflow error in ALib.dll (debugDiag says so and I can see it from the trace above - it goes for very long).

Comment: you have not posted entire info then

Comment: @T.S. I did.  Do you see `ALib.dll!Unknown+be`, then `ALib.dll!Unknown+4c3` repeating over and over again?  That goes on for a long while - I couldn't post the entire screenshot - it would be too long.  Eventually it consumes enough space that a Stack Overflow error is caused.

Comment: you posted a picture. You could post the stack in text format

Comment: You need PDBs in the correct version. PDBs and DLL both contain a checksum and a timestamp. If that does not match, the symbols won't be loaded. You can try loading the crash dump it in WinDbg. WinDbg has capabilities of ignoring mismatched symbols. [.symopt +0x40](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/symbol-options#symopt-load-anything)